# To fetch maximum possible values of a search key from the content of a table using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to search a set of words from the content of a table randomly.
My table 'file_details' has a column 'content' which contains whole content of the file. It has the entries of different files.
I have search a key word through these content of the files only.

For example I have a key to search say '**would be if Merwan**' from column 'content' of table 'file_details'. I want the query to return those files whose 'content' column is consisting the maximum possible elements of my search key together or separately any where in the file. Not necessary that my search key '**would be if Merwan**' should exist together in the file, even if these elements are found separately then I should get that file in my list. This search should be made on the basis of each and every element of the key in the file content.

In short I would say that I want the name of the files in which maximum possible entries of my search key should occur any where in its content considering each and every element of my search key separately.

Please help me out in this. Following is my code:

```
foreach($search_string AS $keySearch => $valSearch){
    if(!empty($valSearch)){
        $strSearchKey .= " f.content LIKE '%".addslashes($valSearch) ."%' OR";
    }
}
$strSearchKey = rtrim($strSearchKey, "OR");

$query = "SELECT filename, redirectlink
FROM file_details f
WHERE (f.content LIKE '%".addslashes($arrParams['search_string']) ."%' OR " . $strSearchKey . ")
AND f.flagactive = 'A'
AND (f.endeffdt = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR f.endeffdt IS NULL OR f.endeffdt > NOW())";
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What do these arrays look like? $search_string, $arrParams

Comment: search_string :: Array
    (
    [0] => would
    [1] => be
    [2] => if
    [3] => Merwan
    )

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($search_string AS $keySearch => $valSearch){
    if(!empty($valSearch)){
        $strSearchKey .= " f.content LIKE '%".addslashes($valSearch) ."%' AND";
    }
}
$strSearchKey = rtrim($strSearchKey, "AND");

$query = "SELECT filename, redirectlink
FROM file_details f
WHERE (f.content LIKE '%".addslashes($arrParams['search_string']) ."%' OR " . $strSearchKey . ")
AND f.flagactive = 'A'
AND (f.endeffdt = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR f.endeffdt IS NULL OR f.endeffdt > NOW())";
```